# get xpath for selectd text

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm creating a epub books reader. After displaying the book i want to allow users to add some annotation to the book.

To display the book, I'm using a wpf webbrowser control that loads local html files

I want to manipulate selected text on this control by creating a context menu or showing a popup

i need to get to get the xpath of the selected text  using javascript functions

```
var uiWebview_xpath = "";

function uiWebview_storeSelection() 
{
    if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined')
     {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);//two range, absolute and relative
        if (range != null) 
        {
            uiWebview_xpath = makeXPath(range.startContainer) + '|' + range.startOffset + '|' + makeXPath(range.endContainer) + '|' + range.endOffset;
            // var x = document.getElementsByName("Hidden1");
            // x.value = uiWebview_xpath;
            return uiWebview_xpath;

        }

}

else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {

    if (document.selection.type == "Text") {

        html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;

    }

    return  html;
}
}
```

but i found that i'm not using the first part of this function and all i get is the html returned by the second part, i want to create xPath for this html

```
//http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/storingSelection1.html

function nsResolver(prefix){
    var ns = {
        'mathml' : 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML', // for example's sake only
        'h' : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
    };
    return ns[prefix];
}

function makeXPath (node, currentPath) {
    /* this should suffice in HTML documents for selectable nodes, XML with namespaces needs more code */
    currentPath = currentPath || '';
    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 3:
        case 4:
            return makeXPath(node.parentNode, 'text()[' + (document.evaluate('preceding-sibling::text()', node, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotLength + 1) + ']');
        case 1:
            return makeXPath(node.parentNode, node.tagName + '[' + (document.evaluate('preceding-sibling::' + 'h:' + node.tagName, node, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotLength + 1) + ']' + (currentPath ? '/' + currentPath : ''));
        case 9:
            return '/' + currentPath;
        default:
            return '';
    }
}
```

i'm a beginner in programming and i'm looking for indication and help, and i want too know if the version of the webbrowser control can influence the result that i get
what is the difference between "document.selection != "undefined" and " window.getSelection != 'undefined'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problém once. All you have to do is adding functions that the IE browser does not recognize.

1. First you have to use the [ierange](https://code.google.com/p/ierange/) that will provide you the object range and not the TextRange
2. Use the [wgxpath](https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/downloads/detail?name=wgxpath.install.js&can=2&q=) that provide you an important function wich is document.evaluate

Here Is my code:

```
    function fixIERangeObject(range, win) { //Only for IE8 and below.
        win = win || window;

        if (!range) return null;
        if (!range.startContainer && win.document.selection) { //IE8 and below

            var _findTextNode = function (parentElement, text) {
                //Iterate through all the child text nodes and check for matches
                //As we go through each text node keep removing the text value (substring) from the beginning of the text variable.
                var container = null, offset = -1;
                for (var node = parentElement.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
                    if (node.nodeType == 3) {//Text node
                        var find = node.nodeValue;
                        var pos = text.indexOf(find);
                        if (pos == 0 && text != find) { //text==find is a special case
                            text = text.substring(find.length);
                        } else {
                            container = node;
                            offset = text.length - 1; //Offset to the last character of text. text[text.length-1] will give the last character.
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Debug Message
                //alert(container.nodeValue);
                return { node: container, offset: offset }; //nodeInfo
            }

            var rangeCopy1 = range.duplicate(), rangeCopy2 = range.duplicate(); //Create a copy
            var rangeObj1 = range.duplicate(), rangeObj2 = range.duplicate(); //More copies :P

            rangeCopy1.collapse(true); //Go to beginning of the selection
            rangeCopy1.moveEnd('character', 1); //Select only the first character
            rangeCopy2.collapse(false); //Go to the end of the selection
            rangeCopy2.moveStart('character', -1); //Select only the last character

            //Debug Message
            // alert(rangeCopy1.text); //Should be the first character of the selection
            var parentElement1 = rangeCopy1.parentElement(), parentElement2 = rangeCopy2.parentElement();


            rangeObj1.moveToElementText(parentElement1); //Select all text of parentElement
            rangeObj1.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', rangeCopy1); //Set end point to the first character of the 'real' selection
            rangeObj2.moveToElementText(parentElement2);
            rangeObj2.setEndPoint('EndToEnd', rangeCopy2); //Set end point to the last character of the 'real' selection

            var text1 = rangeObj1.text; //Now we get all text from parentElement's first character upto the real selection's first character    
            var text2 = rangeObj2.text; //Here we get all text from parentElement's first character upto the real selection's last character

            var nodeInfo1 = _findTextNode(parentElement1, text1);
            var nodeInfo2 = _findTextNode(parentElement2, text2);

            //Finally we are here
            range.startContainer = nodeInfo1.node;
            range.startOffset = nodeInfo1.offset;
            range.endContainer = nodeInfo2.node;
            range.endOffset = nodeInfo2.offset + 1; //End offset comes 1 position after the last character of selection.
        }
        return range;
    }

    function getRangeObject(win) { //Gets the first range object
        win = win || window;
        if (win.getSelection) { // Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera/IE9
            try {
                return win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0); //W3C DOM Range Object
            } catch (e) { /*If no text is selected an exception might be thrown*/ }
        }
        else if (win.document.selection) { // IE8
            var range = win.document.selection.createRange(); //Microsoft TextRange Object
            return fixIERangeObject(range, win);
        }
        return null;
    }

        function nsResolver(prefix) {
            var ns = {
                'mathml': 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML', // for example's sake only
                'h': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
            };
            return ns[prefix];
        }

        function makeXPath(node, currentPath) {
            /* this should suffice in HTML documents for selectable nodes, XML with namespaces needs more code */
            currentPath = currentPath || '';
            switch (node.nodeType) {
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    return makeXPath(node.parentNode, 'text()[' + (document.evaluate('preceding-sibling::text()', node, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotLength + 1) + ']');
                case 1:
                    return makeXPath(node.parentNode, node.tagName + '[' + (document.evaluate('preceding-sibling::' + 'h:' + node.tagName, node, nsResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null).snapshotLength + 1) + ']' + (currentPath ? '/' + currentPath : ''));
                case 9:
                    return '/' + currentPath;
                default:
                    return '';
            }
        }

         var uiWebview_xpath = "";

    function uiWebview_storeSelection() {

    if (typeof window.getSelection != 'undefined') {
    wgxpath.install(window);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0); //two range, absolute and relative
    if (range != null) {
    uiWebview_xpath = makeXPath(range.startContainer) + '|' + range.startOffset + '|' + makeXPath(range.endContainer) + '|' + range.endOffset;
    alert(uiWebview_xpath);
    return uiWebview_xpath;

    }

    }

    else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
        wgxpath.install();
        var range = getRangeObject();
        if (range != null) {
            uiWebview_xpath = makeXPath(range.startContainer) + '|' + range.startOffset + '|' + makeXPath(range.endContainer) + '|' + range.endOffset;
            alert("D"+uiWebview_xpath);
            return uiWebview_xpath;

        }


//        if (document.selection.type == "Text") {

//            html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;

//            alert(html);



//        }

        return "elsif\n:" + "html\n:" + html;
    }
    }
```